# Strange new power supply socket effect

Tags: power-supply, voltage, socket

I bought a new power supply. I have a power strip with 5 sockets, having protection (I guess), and an on/off button. When the button is "on" the button glows red, when its "off" it does not glow.

Now, I have connected the power supply with its power cord to one of the sockets in the strip. The strip button is "off" but the button glows red! I have never seen that happen before. The power supply is "off" during this time.

What that can mean?

When I barely plug the power supply plug into the socket, I guess without touching the ground sides, then the strip button does not glow red, and I have like 13..15V voltage across the power supply GND pin and the strip GND wires.

When I the plug is well inserted into the socket, I have 0V power supply GND to the socket GND, but the button glows red, even that the strip is "off".

One more thing, when the strip button is "off", the plug is in the socket, the button glows red, but if I turn "on" the power supply, the button does not glow anymore, and the power supply does not start.

The power supply works, if I turn "on" the strip with its on/off button. My worries are why the strip glows red when its button is "off" and the power supply is "off".

Please help.

Image of the socket's internals (apologies for not being perfectly clean, it was a bit worse before the photo):
[image: strip internals]

Comment: Which country, what plugs used, grounded devices being connected to ungrounded sockets etc?

Comment: I do not want to bad mouth the power supply or the strip, and so I did not mention. The main power is 220V, but I think that the question is general, and not related to the actual voltage level.

Comment: No I mean which country you are in, to know what type of mains plug you have. It looks like the switch only cuts one mains wire. That is good if you have correctly wired sockets with polarized plugs. If you have wrongly wired polarized plugs, or non-polarized plugs, I would personally refuse to use that power strip and get  one with dual pole switch.

Comment: I do not want to connect the question to any particular country. But will say Europe. I travel (well, less the before 4 years). But that what you write scares me. If the wall socket (the strip is connected) to is wrongly wired, that means that the life wire can always be present in the socket, regardless of the button, which can actually switch on/off the neutral!

Comment: Just checked with the phase meter, that the life wire is on the left in the wall socket, because only there it glows. Wikipedia says that in Europe the life wire has to be on the right. Checked and other sockets, all the same, life wire is on the left. I think I bought the power strip on some trip, many years ago, I do not remember where even. I guess there left-right was different.

Comment: Oh...I confirm. The socket has the life wire always connected, and it switches the neutral wire only. I cannot beleave that I had to buy a power supply to find that one out. Thank you @Justme.

Comment: Well, the country and plug may be important, because different countries have different plugs and different electrical systems. In some countries a single pole switch is OK if the plug is polarized and the wall socket and strip are correctly wired. In some countries it may be illegal to sell a strip with single pole switch because mains plugs are non-polarized.

Comment: VTC Unclear until the country and specific models are given. This is not a guessing game...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can't plug it in in the other orientation, then it is polarized plug, and you are dependent on the socket being wired the way the strip expects it.

It might have been unsafe even in the country where you bought it, or that country has different rules which way neutral and live should be, but in your home, the switch on the strip cuts the neutral wire, leaving live connected to devices behind it.

And the neon indicator light glows due to leakage currents. Leakage currents are caused by capacitive coupling from wires and filter capacitors and the loads themselves.

That is annoying in normal use, but it may be dangerous. These kinds of devices that switch only one mains wire should never ever be relied on that they switch the live wire and de-energize the devices, if you are leaving the devices plugged in while changing lamp or opening up devices to fix them, as there can be live and earth still connected while neutral is disconnected.

Comment: When "right" connected, its all perfect. But when wrong connected then the switch switches the neutral wire and then: when strip's button is "on": *one* strip socket pin glows the meter, *other* does not. When strip is "off" *one* strip socket pin glows the meter, *other* glows the meter *and* glows the lamp of the strip as well any time I'm touching with the meter. Why is that (I'm not going to ask anymore questions)?

Comment: I understand, have seen your edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an assembly error *in the power strip*. The power supply is not the source of this problem, only a conduit for its demonstration.

The switch's indicator is connected in parallel to the switch contact pair, whereas it should be connected parallel to the load. It's usually a benign error, except when using the power strip to power light loads, or loads that draw no current until a threshold voltage is reached on the mains voltage rectifier's output capacitor. Some LED and fluorescent bulbs are just such loads: they'll charge up via the neon, slowly, then blink and shut down, over and over, with sometimes minutes between blinks. Usually the longer the time between the blinks, the brighter they are.

I'd just replace the power strip on principle, or dig into it to fix the wiring. Do what you're comfortable with, and mind the safety!!

Comment: Thank you. I have attached an image, does it look to be as you suspected?

Comment: The wall socket has the life wire on the left, neutral on the right. The switch on the power strip switches on/off the neutral wire, just checked. The phase meter glows on one of the slots of each socket regardless of is the button on or off. I guess that strip is dangerous, right? The life wire had to be turned on/off?